# Trouble appending image and text svg elements to a force-directed tree graph in D3.js

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm learning js, and decided to tackle D3 today.

I'm trying to expand on [this example](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111116/force-collapsible.html). I'd like to map an image over each node, and append text. I found [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12847783/d3-svg-and-javascript-need-to-assign-unique-images-to-dynamically-created-no?rq=1) that was a lot of help for getting started. I've worked details from it into the first example above and come up with [this](https://gist.github.com/savannahniles/6885303#file-problem-html). It looks like something might be up with my attempts to append text and image to "g", and then g to the forces that control the graph.

Any insight would be very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please narrow down where the problem occurs?

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with that [Bl.ock](http://bl.ocks.org/savannahniles/6885303) is that you haven't called your html file `index.html` - Bl.ocks isn't smart enough to recognise other names.  The other things that I noticed was you were referencing d3 locally, with Bl.ocks this won't work unless you upload a d3 which would be pointless when you can just point to:

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

You also need to put this between your header tags.  I've forked your Bl.ock and made these small changes [here](http://bl.ocks.org/phil-pedruco/6890440) and it works just fine.

Of course those things won't help you append images.  You could place the images as background to your circles as in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19202450/adding-an-image-within-a-circle-object-in-d3-javascript/19204833#19204833) or you could just add the image instead trying to attach it to a circle.  I can't see exactly what's going on in you code but the general pattern would be something like:

```
d3.selectAll(".node")
    .data(nodes).enter()
    .append("image")
    .attr("xlink:href", "url")
    .attr("x", x stuff)
    .attr("y", y stuff)
    .attr("height", "16px")
    .attr("width", "16px")
```

I couldn't see that you were binding the data (nodes) to the images which is important.